# How to check if a USB hub supports USB 3.0?

Tags: macbook-pro, usb

I recently bought a USB type-C hub for my MacBook Pro. I found the data transfer speeds to be quite low (from my USB 3.0 external hard disk). I suspect that the USB hub doesn't support USB 3.0 data transfer speeds. How can I confirm this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Open System Information app before you plug in your hub.
2. Navigate to "USB" in the list and click.
3. Note which information isn’t about the device you’re about to test.
4. Then plug in the hub and refresh the window contents.

Here is an example of mine. You can see it is identified as USB 3.0 capable, speed up to 5Gb/sec:

[image: System information]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you elaborate a bit more on point number 3? When the hub isn't plugged in I see 3 "USB 3.1 Bus" listed (The first listing does not have a bus number). As soon as I plug in the hub, the first listing shows a USB 2.0 Hub, while the second listing (Bus number 0x00) shows a USB 3.0 Hub (Similar to the screenshot you've posted). What is this supposed to mean?